# Why classes implicitly derive from only the Object Class?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, object-oriented

I do not have any argument opposing why we need only a single universal class. However why not we have two universal classes, say an Object and an AntiObject Class. In nature and in science we find the concept of duality - like Energy & Dark Energy; Male & Female; Plus & Minus; Multiply & Divide; Electrons & Protons; Integration & Derivation; and in set theory. There are so many examples of dualism that it is a philosophy in itself. In programming itself we see Anti-Patterns which helps us to perform work in contrast to how we use Design patterns. I am not sure, but the usefulness of this duality concept may lie in creating garbage collectors that create AntiObjects that combine with free or loose Objects to destruct themselves, thereby releasing memory. Or may be AntiObjects work along with Objects to create a self-modifying programming language - that allows us to create a safe self modifying code, do evolutionary computing using genetic programming, do hiding of code to prevent reverse engineering.

We call it object-oriented programming. Is that a limiting factor or is there something fundamental I am missing in understanding the formation of programming languages?

Comment: Languages like C++ do not have any root class, so you can build own Object and AntiObject classes if you like.

Comment: @swegi If C++ is superior in this regard then what were the reasons we are moving towards Typed languages - C# and Java. In my understanding, Typed languages provide simplicity and things like Garbage collection, etc. 
Also people have quoted problems with Multiple inheritance before. In this dual system I want classes to either derive from Object or AntiObject but the system does not allow multiple inheritance.

Comment: It is not a question of being superior or otherwise. C# and Java are more modern languages which were designed based on the lessons learned from C++ and other research programming languages. Garbage collection is orthogonal to typing. Both Java and C# avoid the multiple inheritance problem by allowing interfaces separate from classes.  There is no technical reason for disallowing two roots to the object hierarchy.

Comment: In the application to garbage collecting or evolutionary programming, what benefit would introducing an "AntiObject" class bring to these tasks? A process which combined objects and their opposites to collect garbage could just as easily collect garbage without the auxiliary antiobject, for instance. So the short answer is simply that an AntiObject class hasn't actually suggested itself as a useful tool. As for dualism: if you're keen on philosophy as a motivator for PL design, you may as well adopt Hegel's position that the two opposites may be subsumed in a more general Synthesis.

Comment: @kaushal: Typed languages and simplicity, garbage collection, etc are independent of each other. You can add garbage collection to C, for example by adding a custom memory allocation library. C++ is strongly typed if compared to C, but not so strongly typed if compared to most functional languages (e.g. SML, OCaml, etc) because of the casting mechanisms. Multiple Inheritance is needed in C++ to have interfaces. Protocols like in Objective-C are not possible in C++ due to its static nature (unless you build your own runtime).

Comment: @kaushal: In Objective-C for example, there is also no root class per se. There is `NSObject` in the Apple/NextStep world, but you can define your own root class if you like.

Comment: What is this AntiObject, and how does it differ from an Object? Is this just duality for the sake of duality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is only an answer to answer the question in the title.

Languages such as Java have every class deriving from Object for two reasons.

Firstly, to increase the amount of polymorphism available. This was particularly required before generics were added to the language. Without Object,  collection classes would be impossible to write in a useful fashion.

Secondly, there are many methods that classes are expected to have or are useful, and these are collected in Object. By ensuring that all classes inherit from Object, all classes will implement  the same minimal interface.

As mentioned in a comment, C++ does not have a class like Object. C++ is in many ways untyped, so the issues I mention above are not applicable. Also, C++ templates provide a lot of polymorphism and are used to implement collections.

Comment: Great post.  I just thought I would mention how Google's "Go" language handles collections.  In Go, there is no "Object" that everything inherits from, but there is the "empty interface" that everything implements.  In this way they are able to implement collections "generically."

Answer (score 3):

I think the accepted answer covers pretty much the original question, but I would like to supplement it (if I may) slightly by throwing in (quite informally) a few ideas regarding the secondary questions.

From an inheritance point of view, nothing prevents the class hierarchy to have several roots. As it has been pointed out by other peoples, C++, as well as many OO languages don't constraint expressiveness to a single root ancestor class.

However, from a *type theoretic*  point of view (recall that inheritance and subtyping are not the same thing, so I am probably stepping out of the frame of the main question here), a single "top" supertype can make a lot of sense (depending on the type theory of course). For instance, in OCaml, there is a common supertype to all objects (whether class instances, or immediate objects), written `< >` to denote that the object type is empty, i.e. doesn't accept any message. This seems indeed the most general object type we can define, since we cannot remove anything from it to make it more general. Hence, in this conception of object types, there is necessarily a supertype to all object.

Regarding the dual of the root object, scala sports a class called `Nothing`, which curiously is also empty, and is the subtype of every other classes. It cannot be instantiated, but holds enough useful semantic to implement the empty list, which is called `Nil`, and is equal to `List[Nothing]` (as pointed out in comments, it is possible that programmer never directly use that value in most case, making it seemingly not as useful as it is). `Nothing` could be considered a dual of the root type - called `Any` in scala, however these types not only cover classes, but also primitives types, so that everything can be upcasted to `Any`, for instance.

Comment: 1) In Scala, `List[Nothing]` is the minimal inferred type for the empty list, but hardly ever useful. Usually, you want to provide type information to get a (usable) type such as `List[String]`. 2) You say, "a single 'top' supertype makes a lot of sense", but you don't give a reason.

Comment: @Raphael you make 2 very valid points, thank you! I hope my updated answer addresses them somehow.

Comment: In Java and .NET, the universe of class-reference types is essentially the same as the universe of class-instance types, but for the fact that references can exist to abstract classes which cannot actually be instantiated.  From a type-theoretic point of view, I wonder how hard it would be to expand the variety of references, so that an `int[]` which encapsulates ownership of an unsharable array could be distinguished from one which identifies an array which is owned by someone else, or one which is shared among entities that agree never to change it.

Comment: Usually, these type "characteristics" are encoded using polymorphism, either by (1) defining a type for ownership, with as its parameters the type being owned; or by (2) adding a parameter to the type which may be owned, with that parameter being a type representing the owner (a thread, a context, or some other valid runtime entity). For dependently typed language, this owner might even be a value rather than a type.

Comment: What this clearly underline is that we seek to express relationships between types, and polymorphism is a way of encoding that relationship, but we could clearly envision a 3rd option generalizing the previous 2, by defining a type polymorphic on the owner and the owned, or any other kind of relationship we'd like to encode (see for instance [this ocaml library](https://github.com/ocamllabs/higher) which encodes higher kinded types using that idea).

Answer (score 1):

The ability to define collections that can hold arbitrary kinds of things, without needing to define different methods for different kinds of things, is very useful.  Templates in C++ make it possible for a single source file to define collection types that can hold many different kinds of things, but the compiler will have to duplicate the code for every different kind of thing in the collection.  If instead one defines almost all of the types in the system to derive from a single type, then a collection which can hold references to things of that type will be able to hold references to things of almost any type.

This approach does have a limitation, however, which is that it blurs the distinctions between values and entities.  A reference which encapsulates a value by identifying some particular object can be replaced with a reference to a copy of that object without altering its semantics.  A reference which is used to identify an entity, however, cannot be replaced in such fashion.  Either the entity itself will be something that can't be copied (e.g. if it represents a connection to something in the real world) or the entity may encapsulate *the set of references that exist to it*.  A key thing to note is that objects behave as values when either they cannot change or only one reference exists to them, and they behave like entities when multiple references exist.

Blurring the distinction between values and entities makes it difficult for collection types to know whether they should regard their contents as values or entities; this in turn limits the ability of collections to implement things like `equals` or `clone` in useful fashion.  Languages which make a stronger type/entity distinction can have collections do more things automatically than languages which do not, but the distinctions add some complexity, which language designers may or may not feel is justified by the benefits.

Comment: Be careful with the terminology you are employing, when it's not standard : value, type and kind have specific meanings in type theory. Also, I am not quite sure to understand what you mean by "entity". Could you define that word?

Comment: Many terms have particular meanings in various languages, and so I tried to use terms which would avoid such usages.  As for value versus entity, the last sentence of my second paragraph was missing an "or"; does adding it help things?  The key point is that references that are used to encapsulate value are equivalent to other references that identify different objects which hold the same values; references that encapsulate identity are only equivalent to other references to the *same* object.  If references to something encapsulate identity, the thing in question is an entity.

Comment: Right, so every value correspond to an entity, however the process by which comparison is made defines whether we're dealing with values or entities (within your own terminology). Is that what you mean?

Comment: @didierc: The fundamental issue isn't comparison, but control.  Consider two objects `George` and `Larry` of the same class with a private or protected field `Fred`.  If `George` has exclusive controls the states encapsulated by `George.Fred` then it encapsulates value (likewise with `Larry` and `Larry.Fred`).  If `George.Fred` identifies objects whose state can change outside their George's control, then that object is an entity.  If `George.Fred` and `Larry.Fred` are values, then if the observable properties of `George.Fred` and `Larry.Fred` match, they will continue to do so unless...

Comment: ...`George` or `Larry` changes them, so they should be regarded as equivalent.  If their states could independently be changed without `George` or `Larry`'s involvement, then they should not be regarded as equivalent.  The method of comparison isn't what makes something a value or an entity, but things should only report themselves as equivalent if there's no way they could become non-equivalent without the involvement of the thing that's asking for the comparison.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but is there one or more resources I could have a look at which define that notion of "entity" more formally?

Comment: @didierc: Different people use terms somewhat differently; discussions of "domain driven design" separate objects into "values" and "entities", but DDD has somewhat stricter rules about how value objects and entities should be designed and interact (rather than calling that things that obey certain rules "values", and everything else "entities").  As such, my use of the terms is not quite standard, but there are so far as I know no better terms to distinguish between references that encapsulate state which is controlled by the owner of the reference, versus references to state...

Comment: ...which can be changed in ways the reference-owner cannot control.  The attention given to this distinction has been insufficient to lead to consistently-used terminology for describing it, but I would posit that the designers of future object-oriented languages and frameworks should pay it great heed.  There is a major semantic difference between the only reference to a particular `int[]`, versus a sharable reference to an `int[]` that nobody will ever change, versus a shared reference to an `int[]` that will change. The type system treats them the same, but they're really very different.

Comment: Totally agree with you regarding terminology. I was confused, and thus my wording was perhaps too strong. So, now it seems that the notion of entity is just the expression of a particular type trait (like constant/mutable). Support basically requires formalizing the notion within a type system as you said. There are basically 2 outcomes I envision from such formalization: the ability to perform more compile time checks with usage contracts on values (which language object controls what) and the one of enforcing runtime access policies, which is another way of saying security.

Comment: Maybe [this paper](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/talc/papers/sa-popl00.pdf) could be on topic? At any rate, I encourage you to include in your answer either a small explanation of what an entity is, or a reference on the topic.

Comment: @didierc: I'll look at the paper.  I thought my second paragraph explained what I meant by "entity"; how should I make my intention more clear?  As for references to other literature, I don't think I've seen literature regarding as fundamental the distinction between a reference whose target is under the exclusive control of the reference's holder, versus a reference whose target may be changed outside the control of that particular reference's holder, so I can't cite any.  As for outcomes, there's a third you haven't mentioned: the removal of ambiguity regarding deep-vs-shallow comparisons...

Comment: ...and cloning operations. In C++, the need to actively track all pointers to avoid memory leaks compels a solid model of "ownership" even for objects which should, semantically, be "ownerless". The creators of Java and .NET correctly recognized that the need to have user code track ownership of semantically-ownerless objects was a nuisance which should be eliminated, but unfortunately failed to realize that many objects cannot be used correctly without tracking ownership, and simplifying the language to eliminate the concept of "ownership" merely forces programmers to track it manually.

Comment: I just took a quick glance at the paper; I'll look at it more later, but my interests are more with being able to express semantics declaratively than with type-based "security".  Among other things, it may sometimes be useful for code to make promises that cannot be verified at compile-time or even at run-time.  For example, consider a function `string InvariantUppercase(string st)` which, given a string, converts it to uppercase using the invariant culture, and which uses `ConditionalWeakTable` to cache strings which it has converted.  Two distinct strings with identical text...

Comment: ...could get cached in different entries of the `ConditionalWeakTable`.  The fact that the strings would get mapped to different table slots despite containing the same characters would suggest to a code verifier that they're being used as entities rather than values, but if the contents of the cache table slots associated with equivalent strings will always be equivalent, that would imply the strings are--from the standpoint of outside code--used as values.  Were I designing a framework, I would have the rule that if two references are used as values, and they have reported themselves as...

Comment: ...equivalent, then the framework would be allowed to arbitrarily substitute one reference for the other at any such time as it saw fit.  Code which casts a "reference to value" to a general "reference" could be assured that the general reference would retain its identity, but applying such a cast twice to the same value reference could arbitrarily yield two references to the same object, or different objects.  Code could test values for reference equality; non-equivalent things would compare reference-unequal, and equivalent things could arbitrarily compare equal or not.